# What kind of authority does Rainbow Dash have?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In *Hurricane Fluttershy*, Rainbow Dash takes charge of the Pegasi of Ponyville to lift water for Cloudsdale. Does she have some sort of official command, or is she just taking charge of her own accord?

Comment: Rainbow Dash does everything like a boss. Even if she isn't necessarily.

Comment: @Tacroy You know with the right spin on that it'd work as an answer.

Comment: I realized that after I commented, but I'd need some citations and I can't exactly research MLP at work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to the wikia](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Rainbow_Dash#Ponyville), Rainbow Dash is in charge of managing the weather in Ponyville. Presumably this leads into other Ponyville Pegasi naturally looking towards her for leadership in other situations (the events in *Hurricane Fluttershy* for example).

Beyond that, it's likely the case that she's just highly confident and more likely than usual to find herself leading in various situations.

Comment: Considering "She's in charge", in case needs for more pegasi in weather management arises, she remains in charge - of the weather, and as extension, of ponies managing it. Another example situation: Winter Wrap-up.

Comment: Add the breezies passing through PonyVille to this. She is managing the pegasi making the breeze.

Comment: It seems to me that the hurricane thing would naturally be led by the weather leader of Ponyville.